# Show VSTS code coverage results on Github readme

Tags: azure-devops

My code is hosted in GitHub and I run CI builds in VSTS with VSTest which outputs code coverage results. I can see these results in the finished build page, but it would be nice to be able to display these on our GitHub repo like our build status badge and nuget badges are. Does anyone know of a standard way to do this with VSTS (i.e. built in task) or is this something I would need to handle in a script myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show VSTS build results (such as code coverage results) on README, you need to handle it by your own script.

The main idea is get related information for build logs and commit the information in README.

Deatil steps as below:

1. Add a PowerShell task at the end of your CI build definition

   In powershell script, you need to get test results from build logs, format and commit the information in README. Finally push the changes to your github repo. Functions in the powershell script need to be achieved as following steps.
2. Get related build logs

   You can get the current build logs by using [Timeline REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/timeline/get):

   ```
   GET https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/timeline?api-version=4.1
   ```

   And you can search logs of a certain test by task name (such as `VSTest`):

   ```
   {
       "id": "407545ba-79a9-55a7-47dd-583380011305",
       "parentId": "df143ba0-1c7a-5b21-02e1-d41a394e29c9",
       "type": "Task",
       "name": "VsTest - testAssemblies",
       "startTime": "2018-05-01T08:20:45.3233333Z",
       "finishTime": "2018-05-01T08:21:55.3733333Z",
       "currentOperation": null,
       "percentComplete": null,
       "state": "completed",
       "result": "succeeded",
       "resultCode": null,
       "changeId": 14,
       "lastModified": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
       "workerName": "WXV-XINDO-12R2",
       "order": 4,
       "details": null,
       "errorCount": 0,
       "warningCount": 0,
       "url": null,
       "log": {
           "id": 5,
           "type": "Container",
           "url": "https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/f7855e29-6f8d-429d-8c9b-41fd4d7e70a4/_apis/build/builds/2897/logs/5"
       },
       "task": {
           "id": "ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9",
           "name": "VSTest",
           "version": "1.0.86"
       }
   ```

   Then you can get the VSTest build log by the url https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/f7855e29-6f8d-429d-8c9b-41fd4d7e70a4/_apis/build/builds/2897/logs/5 (as above example).
3. Collect the information and format README

   You can get the information for your needs, and format the README file.
4. Commit and push changes to your github repo

   ```
   git checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName)
   git add .
   git commit -m 'update README'
   git push origin $(Build.SourceBranchName)
   ```

**Note:**

- Since you need to push changes of the README during CI build, you'd better add a step in your CI build definition to check whether build triggered by README update.
- And since git command usually show non-standard output, you need to deselect Fail on Standard Error option for PowerShell task.

  [image]